# How to split a simple HTML page into multiple React components and share states?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React Js. Could someone please explain how to translate this example to ReactJs? Specifically, if you have to organize the code into 3 components, how would you share the states between these component?

```
<label for="inputNumberOfCheckboxes">Enter number of checkboxes:</label> <input type="text" id ="inputNumberOfCheckboxes">
<ol id="listOfCheckboxes">
</ol>
<p id="printNumberOfSelectedCheckboxes">None</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const inputNumberOfCheckboxes = document.getElementById('inputNumberOfCheckboxes');
    const listOfCheckboxes = document.getElementById('listOfCheckboxes');
    const printNumberOfSelectedCheckboxes = document.getElementById('printNumberOfSelectedCheckboxes');
    inputNumberOfCheckboxes.addEventListener('change', () => {
        const n = parseInt(inputNumberOfCheckboxes.value);
        listOfCheckboxes.innerHTML = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            listOfCheckboxes.innerHTML += `
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </li>`;
        }
        const refreshCount = () => {
            const count = listOfCheckboxes.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length;
            printNumberOfSelectedCheckboxes.innerHTML = `${count} checked`;
        };
        for (let checkbox of listOfCheckboxes.childNodes) {
            checkbox.addEventListener('change', refreshCount);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That question and its answers don't cover how to generate the checkboxes.

Comment: If you know of a better way to frame this question for posterity, please add a comment. Please don't just downvote my question because that wouldn't help other learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState([]);

  const getRows = () => {
    const length = inputValue > 0 ? inputValue : 0;
    const arr = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1);

  return (
    <ol>
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <li key={item}>
          <input
            onChange={() => {
              const items = checkedItems.includes(item)
                ? checkedItems.filter((num) => num !== item)
                : [...checkedItems, item];

              setCheckedItems(items);
            }}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checkedItems.includes(item)}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
}
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label htmlFor="inputNumberOfCheckboxes">
        Enter number of checkboxes:
      </label>
      <input
        name="inputNumberOfCheckboxes"
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        value={inputValue}
      />
      <ol>{getRows()}</ol>
      {inputValue > 0 ? null : <p>None</p>}
      checked items: {checkedItems.length}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bogdan-21v8c)

Splitted:

`Input.js`

```
export default function Input({ name, value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={name}>Enter number of checkboxes:</label>
      <input
        name={name}
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`List.js`

```
export default function List({ inputValue, checkedItems, setCheckedItems }) {
  const length = inputValue > 0 ? inputValue : 0;
  const arr = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1);

  return (
    <ol>
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <li key={item}>
          <input
            onChange={() => {
              const items = checkedItems.includes(item)
                ? checkedItems.filter((num) => num !== item)
                : [...checkedItems, item];
              setCheckedItems(items);
            }}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checkedItems.includes(item)}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
}
```

`Summary.js`

```
export default function Summary({ inputValue, checkedItems }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {inputValue > 0 ? null : <p>None</p>}
      checked items: {checkedItems.length}
    </p>
  );
}
```

`App.js`

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input onChange={setInputValue} value={inputValue} />
      <List
        name="inputNumberOfCheckboxes"
        inputValue={inputValue}
        checkedItems={checkedItems}
        setCheckedItems={setCheckedItems}
      />
      <Summary inputValue={inputValue} checkedItems={checkedItems} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-neumann-ijnkn)

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense. Is there a reason why you didn't split this into 3 components? How would the code look like (sharing states) to split it into 3 components (the text input, the ordered list, and the paragraph)?

Comment: @Believe2014 I updade codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-neumann-ijnkn

Comment: Your updated code works great. Would you please make a separate answer? I would like to keep your previous answer (because it's great). And will mark you new answer as accepted. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Believe2014 I edited my question, it is 2 solutions there.